# How to access nested resources in API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I have a Ember app that uses a Rails API.  I have a teams table and a referees table, both link to another table called refereeTeamStats.  I am trying to get all the refereeTeamStats for a team and include the referee resource so I can get the referee's name.  In short, I need my Ember app to call `/teams/:team_id/refereeTeamStats?include=referee`
Initially I had my app get the refereeTeamStats through the route by doing this:

```
model() {
  return this.modelFor('teams/show').get('refereeTeamStats');
}
```

This will call `/teams/:team_id/refereeTeamStats` however, this will not include the referee resource.  What is the best way that I can get the refereeTeamStats with including a resource (referee) on a nested resource (refereeTeamStats)?

Comment: What resources do you pass in response of that method ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `refereeTeamStats` serializer could implement the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin`, and define

```
attrs: {
  referee: { embedded: 'always' }
}
```

So that if your API returns the `referee` key in the `refereeTeamStats` payload, ember will deserialize it to the correct object.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going about this a different way. Since I was using the [JSONAPI::Resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) gem, I was able to do `/refereeTeamStats?filter[team_id]=:team_id&include=referee` instead. To do that, I did this:

```
model() {
  const team = this.modelFor('teams/show');
  return this.store.query('refereeTeamStat', {filter: {team_id: team.get('id')}, include: 'referee'});
}
```